# DBD::Mock specify output values for stored procedure

Tags: perl, testing

I'm trying to use [DBD::Mock](http://search.cpan.org/~dichi/DBD-Mock-1.45/lib/DBD/Mock.pm) to test code that uses a database. So far, normal SQL queries work just fine, however I'm somewhat at a loss as to how I can test code that calls stored procedures. Using the `bound_params` key for the `DBD::Mock::Session->new` constructor, I can specify input parameters, but I can't seem to find a way of setting up mock results of the parameters that are bound using `DBI::StatementHandle::bind_param_inout()`.

To provide an example for the code that is going to be tested, have a look at the following:

```
use DBI;
my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:Mock', '', '', { RaiseError => 1, PrintError => 1 });
my $sth = $dbh->prepare(q{
BEGIN
  some_stored_proc(i_arg1 => :arg1, o_arg2 => :arg2);
END;
});
my ($arg1, $arg2) = ('foo', 'bar');
$sth->bind_param(':arg1', $arg1);
$sth->bind_param_inout(':arg2', \$arg2, 200);
$sth->execute();
print STDERR "OUTPUT VALUE OF arg2 = $arg2\n";
```

Now, I want to seed the DB with `'frobnication'` for the `arg2` parameter, such that when the above code is executed, the `$arg2` variable contains this string and the output is

> OUTPUTVALUE OF arg2 = frobnication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing. Essentially the main work goes into the overriding of the `DBD::Mock::st::bind_param_inout` method.

```
use DBI;
use DBD::Mock;
use DBD::Mock::st;
use Carp;

# array of values to be bound on each invocation
my @values = qw/frobnication/;
# dummy variable to trick DBD::Mock into thinking it got the same reference for
# bind_param_inout and bound_params (the former is usually not in the control of
# the testing code, hence this hack).
my $dummy = undef;
# keep reference to the original bind_param_inout method
my $bind_param_inout_orig = \&DBD::Mock::st::bind_param_inout;
# override with our mocked version that assigns a value to the reference.
# notice that it does so at the bind_param_inout call, *NOT* the execute call!
local *DBD::Mock::st::bind_param_inout = sub {
  my ($self, $param_num, $val, $size) = (shift, shift, shift, shift);
  $bind_param_inout_orig->($self, $param_num, \$dummy, $size, @_);
  $$val = shift @values or Carp::confess '@values array exhausted!';
};

# set up the mock session
my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:Mock:', '', '',
  { RaiseError => 1, PrintError => 1 });
$dbh->{mock_session} = DBD::Mock::Session->new('foo_session' => (
  {
    statement => qr/BEGIN\n\s*some_stored_proc/,
    results => [],
    bound_params => ['foo', \$dummy]
  }));

# this is the code to be tested

my $sth = $dbh->prepare(q{
BEGIN
  some_stored_proc(i_arg1 => :arg1, o_arg2 => :arg2);
END;
});
my ($arg1, $arg2) = ('foo', 'bar');
$sth->bind_param(':arg1', $arg1);
$sth->bind_param_inout(':arg2', \$arg2, 200);
$sth->execute();
print STDERR "OUTPUT VALUE OF arg2 = $arg2\n";
```

Comment: This works thank you, I did however experience issues with the value of `0` though so I had to change the `shift` statement to a less destructive variation. `$$val = shift @values;` since _shifting_ `0` returns `0` and hence the subroutines dies. Ref: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use  [Sub::Override](http://search.cpan.org/~ovid/Sub-Override-0.09/lib/Sub/Override.pm) to override this sub.

You could modify your mocked object like this and create a new mocked sub.

```
$mocked_dbd->mock( 'bind_param_inout',&mocked_bind_param_inout );
```

It looks like to me that this method is mocked here: http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/DICHI/DBD-Mock-1.45/lib/DBD/Mock/st.pm

Maybe this will work:

```
my @rs_foo = (
    [ 'this', 'that' ],
    [ 'this_one', 'that_one' ],
    [ 'this_two', 'that_two' ],
);
# the first one ordered
$dbh->{mock_add_resultset} = [ @rs_foo ];

use Data::Dumper;
my $mocked_records = $sth->{mock_records};
print Dumper($mock_records);
```

Comment: Sorry, you lost me there... If in the first code example `mocked_dbd` is a database handle, I didn't see any `mock` method in the `DBD::Mock` docs, so what are you referring to here? And how is the second code block going to help me? I'm not retrieving a result set, there is no SQL involved. I just call a stored procedure with parameters, some of which are output parameters for which I want to seed a value.

Comment: The DBD::Mock is inherit the mock method from its parent.

Comment: The code part: I checked the code in st.pm and the test files and it think it may work. Sorry, this module is not installed here, I am not able to try it out.